# Asking to get an item in the shop just to check how it works

Tags: phrase-request, questions

I am wondering how people ask if they can handle a particular item in a shop, to check how it works or look at it more closely.

My guess would be "Can I watch it?" but it is probably not so good.

Comment: In addition to the suggestions below, you could also ask to “check it out” or “try it out” if you wanted to be more clear that you would be manipulating and/or otherwise interacting with the object. You may already be aware of various ways of making requests, but I’ll add that your choice between “can”, “could”, and “may” can make your request more formal/proper/polite(/subservient/obsequious), as can the inclusion of “please”. How much familiarity is appropriate for the situation will be a matter of judgement, but most people would agree: you’ll get a “yes” more often if you _ask nicely._

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would say something like:

> Could I take a look at it, please?

The key distinction here is that ['take a look'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_a_look) can be used similarly to ['inspect'](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/inspect) or ['examine'](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/examine) in this case. For example, you could instead ask:

> Could I examine it, please?

Whereas ['watch'](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/watch) in this sense would mean to observe something over a period of time, such as watching TV or a football match.

Comment: "May I see it, please?" is another way to say this.

Comment: +1 to the answer and @J.R.'s comment. Also I'd note that you're more likely to use *that* than *it*; you're probably indicating the object while you're saying this. I suppose *it* could make sense ("Do you have the Thingymabob 9000?" "Yes, we do." "May I see it, please?"). But if you're indicating the item without previous reference, use *that*.

Comment: @WendiKidd: If my experience is typical, the item in question is in a glass case with several similar items, and the conversation goes something like this :^) **me**: "May I see one of the watches, please? I mean the one with the silver wristband." **clerk, pointing**: "You mean this one?" **me**: "No, not that one, the one over on that side." [_clerk points to a different watch_] "Almost – I mean the one behind that one." [_clerk moves hand back a little bit, and points to the right watch_] "Yes, that one... may I see it, please?"

Comment: "Could I examine it" is a little stilted (in US English that is :) unless this was evidence in a court. Since it's a shop, I'd just as "Can I take a look at it, please ?"

Comment: And "Can I try it, please?" if it's something you want to use to see how it works (but "try it on" for clothes!).